# Setting username in Mercurial .hgrc file

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I have been browsing SO and Google for a solution to my basic problem, and so far I have had no luck.

I am brand new to Mercurial and have just installed it on my Mac. I am using it for personal version control and will not be communicating with a central server (yet).

When I try to commit files, I get **abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")**. The common solution to this problem is putting the following in ~/.hgrc

```
[ui]
username = Firstname Lastname <firstname.lastname@example.net>
```

which I have done, but the error remains. It just won't read the file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could be some typo on your part. Please verify that `cat ~/.hgrc` (copy-paste that to a shell) produces the necessary config data. Update your question with the (appropriately anonimized) output.

Comment: @Adam Mercurial.ini is Windows only.

Comment: @PaulS Yeah I suspected as much :-(

Comment: What is the output of `hg.exe showconfig | grep ui`?

Comment: Does `hg commit -u username -m "msg"` works?

Comment: Sorry for the delay -- I currently have not internet access on the computer that I have been setting up Mercurial. Well the problem is "fixed", in that restarting my computer (for the first time in a month or so) seems to have fixed the problem (however, the reliability of this is unknown).

Comment: @danielkullmann: just a small note: instead of using `grep` (which is normally not there on Windows), then just do `hg showconfig ui` to get the settings from the `[ui]` section.

Answer (score 31):

For future reference: use

```
$ hg showconfig ui --debug
```

to see the settings from the `[ui]` section and to **see the files Mercural reads** for configuration settings. That should help you along if you ever have to debug such a case again.